At most how many zero points can the function $e^x - p(x)$ have, if $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$?
At most how many zero points can the function $e^x - p(x)$ have, if $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree n?
My idea is $n+1$. Since $p(x)$ can have up to $n$ real roots and the function behaves like $p(x)$ for small $x$ values and $e^x$ grows faster than any polynomial, if $p(x) \rightarrow \infty$,  then the function tends to $-\infty$ while $p(x)$ dominates, but once $e^x$ "takes over" (i.e. for large enough values of $x$), the function tends to $\infty$ and so it "crosses" the $x$ axis another time.
Is this right? If so, how could I write this more formally?

Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2120037/42969
